# Spring Boot Validation not redirecting back to the form

Tags: spring-boot, validation, annotations

I am trying to validate a form in a spring boot application. I have added an annotation validation in the entity class. When I click the submit button of the form, I want the validation to happen and the error message displayed in the form.

I am using Spring boot 3.0.5.

**pom.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sampleapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>sampleapp</name>
    <description>Sample App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>`
```

**Relevant portion of the Entity Class**

```
  `  @Size(min = 10, max = 10, message="Mobile should be of length exact 10.")
     @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
   private String mobile;`
```

**relevant portion of template file**

```
`   <form method="post" th:action="@{/saveCustomer}" th:object="${customer}" class="form">
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Mobile Number</label>
 <input class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile"
th:field="*{mobile}" type="text"/>
<div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('mobile')}" th:errors="*{mobile}"></div>
</div>
</form>`
```

**Controller Method**
I am using Jakarta validation.

// I am checking if the result has errors and if so redirecting back to the original form.

```
` @RequestMapping("/saveCustomer")
       public String saveCustomer( @Valid  Customer customer, BindingResult result,
Model model ) { 
          if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "createcustomer";
            }
           customerRepository.save(customer);
           return "confirmationpage";
       }`
```

**Expected Result**
Error to be displayed in the form

**Actual result**
When the form is submitted, the following error gets thrown with the error message that I have specified. But the controller method is not invoked at all, so redirection to the original form is not happening.

`*http POST error with status 400 is displayed in the browser.*`

**Error thrown**
`*WARN[0;39m [35m16008[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.String com.sampleapp.controller.TransactionsController.saveCustomer(com.sampleapp.entity.Customer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model): [Field error in object 'customer' on field 'mobile': rejected value [11]; codes [Size.customer.mobile,Size.mobile,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [customer.mobile,mobile]; arguments []; default message [mobile],10,10]; default message [**Mobile should be of length exact 10.**]] ]*`

What am I doing wrong here. How do I redirect back to the form? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Provide **@ModelAttribute("customer")** before **@Valid**

Comment: Thanks. I did it. The issue still persists. This is the updated method definition.                                   @RequestMapping("/saveCustomer")
       public String saveCustomer( @ModelAttribute("customer") @Valid Customer customer, BindingResult result, Model model ) { 
          if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "createcustomer";
            }
           customerRepository.save(customer);
           return "confirmationpage";
       }

Comment: Btw it should be PostMapping instead of  RequestMapping

Comment: Ah yes, I was trying out things. Now used PostMapping, still the same issue. The validation is happening but http 400 error is still resulting in the controller method not being called. What could be happening.                                                                                                                        @PostMapping("/saveCustomer") public String saveCustomer( @ModelAttribute("customer") @Valid Customer customer, BindingResult result, Model model ) { if (result.hasErrors()) { return "createcustomer"; } customerRepository.save(customer); return "confirmationpage"; }

Comment: Ok, and how does java class Customer looks like with its validation-related annotations?

Comment: This is the method definition in the Customer class.  I am using jakarta validations.                               
          import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
.....
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10, message="Mobile should be of length exact 10.")
  @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
     private String mobile;
  ...
  }

Comment: Try @JsonProperty("mobile") above @Size

Comment: Same MethodArgumentNotValidException and http 400 status after including.                      @JsonProperty("mobile")
@Size(min = 10, max = 10, message="Mobile should be of length exact 10.")
@Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
private String mobile;

Comment: I suppose your controller class is annotated with Controller, not RestController ?

Comment: Yes.

@Controller
public class TransactionsController {...                                                                                    If I specify valid data for all fields, the controller method gets called and the data gets saved.  Only in case of errors is the method not called, the error seems to be thrown before the method is executed.